# Customizing Android Overflow menu which pops up when pressing hardware button

Tags: android, android-actionbar, optionmenu, overflow-menu

I am able to style overflow menu which pops up from action bar but I am not able to style overflow menu which pops up from hardware menu button.

I am interested in styling states of selector for the item in menu.

any ideas are welcome?

Comment: are you using a custom layout (XML) for styling the overflow menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For customize the popup menu which is displayed with the hardware menu button, you need to have this item in your app theme:

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@drawable/ab_item_selector</item>  
</style>
```

You can change `@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light` according to your needs (as `Holo` or something else). Then, the drawable named `ab_item_selector` might be this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- selected state -->
    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/item_selected" 
        android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <!-- pressed state -->
    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/item_pressed" 
        android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <!-- normal state -->
    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/item_disabled"></item>
</selector>
```

Hope this helps.

---

**UPDATE**

For dividers, I'm not sure but it might be:

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/CustomDropDown</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/CustomDropDown</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomDropDown" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dip</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@drawable/dropdown_divider</item>
</style>
```

Comment: With this I can see the background color changing but I do not see the pressed state reflected properly. But I think we are getting near, may be need fix selector now.

Comment: Yes, I saw that you already updated answer with selected. I should have refreshed but this fixes my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, you have to play with the selector states as focused, pressed/focused, pressed/selected, etc. Personally, I used focused/enabled, focused/pressed and pressed.

Comment: Any Idea how to customize those dividers in menu item.

Comment: I updated my answer, @VendettaDroid. However, be careful with this item, it customizes all the listview in your app. Not sure but it might be this attribute to stylize your menu. HTH

Comment: I will try and comment back here but I think, I already tried this style but I will double make sure and share results here.

Comment: Did that actually work for styling dividers for the overflow on hw key phones? Because it is not working for me.

Comment: @VendettaDroid Hi how did you resolve the issue, finally, if you did resolve it?